# Why should I use my own server to validate iOS receipt?

Tags: ios, iphone, security, in-app-purchase

I want to validate iOS receipt.

I thought I would send a receipt to the App Store verification server (https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt or https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt).

But Apple reference says:

> It is not possible to build a trusted connection between a user’s
>   device and the App Store directly because you don’t control either end
>   of that connection.

And apple recommend sending a receipt to my server then send it to the App Store verification server to validate.

(https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateRemotely.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010573-CH104-SW1)

I don't understand why a connection between a device and the App Store is not trusted regardless of using HTTPS connection.

Comment: because user can jailbreak their device

Comment: @BryanChen Thank you for your comment, but How can I make a connection between a device and my server secure when jailbreaked?

Comment: I don't know, maybe you can't. But if every app use a single server to verify IPA, then the cracker only need to make one patch and works for all app. On the other hand, if every app use its own server with different API to verify IPA, the cracker have to spend time for each app to break it.

Answer (score 7):

Your app is running on hardware controlled by the user. They have physical access to it, and can do anything they want with it. The operating system doesn't make it easy for a user to mess with things, but it can be done and hackers do it.

You can validate the iOS receipt on the iOS device. But you cannot be sure that the receipt is actually valid. The user could have hacked the device to make you think the receipt is valid.

> I don't understand why a connection between a device and the App Store is not trusted regardless of using HTTPS connection.

HTTPS does not protect you from a hacker who has physical control over iOS device. A hacker can install different SSL keys on the device, allowing it to connect with a different server.

When your app tries to communicate with Apple's server, any network administrator can change it so that some other server is contacted instead of Apple's one. This server would normally be rejected because the SSL key will be untrusted... but if the user controls the device, they can make it trust an invalid SSL key.

Your server, however, is controlled by you. Your customers do not have physical access to it. And therefore your server (hopefully!) cannot be hacked. This means your server can be trusted, unlike the device. When your server establishes an SSL connection to Apple's server, you know you really are talking to Apple's server. Not one that your user installed to bypass in-app purchasing.

So, if the user buys something in your app... you don't want to store the thing being purchased inside the app. You want to store it on a server, and that server only sends the purchased data to the device after it has verified the receipt with Apple's server.

If you don't want to spend money running your own server, then you will simply have to accept that any tech savvy person with a few hours of free time can create fake iOS purchase receipts and convince your device that they are valid.

Comment: And even with all that nothing is guaranteed. In any case, nowadays you can rent a virtual private server for 10 bucks/month, it is really cheap.

Comment: @Havenard it is guaranteed, if you do it from your server and your server is properly secured.

Comment: As @BryanChen (question's comment) says, [device] <-> [my server] connection is also insecure but it is more secure than [device] <-> [App Store] connection, right?

Comment: @md_develop *anything* involving the device is insecure. You do not have any control at all over the device. Only your server is secure. And Apple's server is pretty secure too, since they're generally an upstanding company who will not try to bypass your in-app purchase system.

Comment: Just to be perfectly clear, a device cannot possibly verify anything. It is impossible to prevent the owner of the device from modifying how it works. Your server can verify them however. If you're selling something, such as access to some data, then just store the data on the server and have the server verify the purchase before giving it to the device. Your users can edit the executable code of your app, and they can edit the operating system. With common/shared APIs like Apple's purchasing system, there are publicly available tools a user can run on their own phone to avoid paying

Comment: I don't get it. The middle man can also intercept the data between device and my own server right?

Comment: @neobie they can intercept, but they can't forge a purchase receipt signed using Apple's private key.